# Flutter/Dart : read TLS certificate file

Tags: flutter, dart, ssl, grpc, tls1.2

I'm trying to read the file `tls/cert.pem` from my flutter client code as below:

```
final channel = ClientChannel('10.0.2.2',
    port: 9000,
    options: ChannelOptions(
      credentials: ChannelCredentials.secure(
        certificates: new File('tls/cert.pem').readAsBytesSync(),
        authority: 'localhost',
      ),
      codecRegistry:
      CodecRegistry(codecs: const [GzipCodec(), IdentityCodec()]),
    ),
  );
```

Please note that `tls/cert.pem` file is already added to the `pubspec.yaml` asset list:

```
assets:
    - tls/cert.pem  
    ...
```

**My error messages :**

```
E/flutter (24635): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = 'tls/cert.pem' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
E/flutter (24635): #0      _File.throwIfError (dart:io/file_impl.dart:629:7)
E/flutter (24635): #1      _File.openSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:473:5)
E/flutter (24635): #2      _File.readAsBytesSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:533:18)
...
```

While I'm getting the error message above, anyone can answer what's wrong with my code and settings?

doublechecked the relative path, file existence, removal from the asset list

Comment: You need to read the asset using the bundle (not File). I'll link a reference.